# laravel:send notification with (data) when update a record

Tags: laravel

Problem: how can I display data with update function?

the notification is sent but witout data that I specified in  this function :
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'data'=>$this->booking->num_ch
           ];
    }

it works with store function  but it dosn't with update function

my notification class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;


use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use App\Booking;

class NewMessage extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    public $booking;

    public function __construct(Booking $booking)
    {
        //
        $this->booking = $booking;

    }


    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }


    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'data'=>$this->booking->num_ch
           ];                  
    }
```

my update function :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Booking;
use App\User;
use Notification;
use App\Notifications\NewMessage;

class DispoController extends Controller
{


    public function update(Request $request,$id,Booking $booking)
    {
        //  
         Booking::findOrFail($id)->update([
         'num_ch'=>$request->num_ch,
         'type'=>$request->type,
         'statut'=>$request->statut,
         'enfants'=>$request->enfants,
         'adultes'=>$request->adultes,


        ]);

        auth()->user()->notify(new NewMessage($booking)); // notification


      return redirect()->route('booking.index')->with(['success'=>'succés']);

    }
```

it shows just "new booking"

```
 @foreach(Auth::user()->unreadNotifications as $not)
         <li>
          <a class="dropdown-item"  >new booking {{$not->data['data']}}</a>
         </li>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public function update(Request $request,$id,Booking $booking)
    {
        //  
        Booking::findOrFail($id)->update([
            'num_ch'=>$request->num_ch,
            'type'=>$request->type,
            'statut'=>$request->statut,
            'enfants'=>$request->enfants,
            'adultes'=>$request->adultes,

        ]);
        auth()->user()->notify(new NewMessage(Booking::findOrFail($id)));

         // notification


        return redirect()->route('info_client.index')->with(['success'=>'succés']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your not capturing the saved booking, should be like so

```
public function update(Request $request,$id,Booking $booking)
{
    //  
     $booking = Booking::findOrFail($id)->update([
         'num_ch'=>$request->num_ch,
         'type'=>$request->type,
         'statut'=>$request->statut,
         'enfants'=>$request->enfants,
         'adultes'=>$request->adultes,
    ]);

    auth()->user()->notify(new NewMessage($booking)); // notification


  return redirect()->route('booking.index')->with(['success'=>'succés']);

}
```

So your passing in an empty booking from the function call and passing that to the notification and not the updated record.

But you can simplify the whole thing by doing this

```
public function update(Request $request, Booking $booking)
{
    //  
     $booking->update([
         'num_ch'=>$request->num_ch,
         'type'=>$request->type,
         'statut'=>$request->statut,
         'enfants'=>$request->enfants,
         'adultes'=>$request->adultes,
    ]);

    auth()->user()->notify(new NewMessage($booking)); // notification


    return redirect()->route('booking.index')->with(['success'=>'succés']);
}
```

So instead of passing both id and booking just pass in the booking which should automatically be found from the Route and container.

Comment: u gave me some indix thnx and I got you well, after some tries it works like that:`    
   
        auth()->user()->notify(new NewMessage(Booking::findOrFail($id)));
    
         // notification

Comment: update your answer to acceptet and thanks a lot again